# Android Studio Error when i am running my app on phone

Tags: android

Android Studio Error when i am running my app on phone
the massage error look like this :

$ adb shell am start -n "com.rgamestudio.aplikasi/com.rgamestudio.aplikasi.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Unexpected error while executing: am start -n "com.rgamestudio.aplikasi/com.rgamestudio.aplikasi.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while Launching activity

Comment: Please share code of `manifest` file.

Comment: As @AshishTiwari said please share manifest file